# Run JAVA war file from command line with classpath to start API

Tags: java, api, heroku, classpath

I'm having big problems running my java api war file from the command line after ive packaged it with maven.

I'm trying to run it using the following command from the target folder where my war file is located.

```
java -cp silverkissen.war se/consys/silverkissen/heroku/Main
```

And alot  of other variations but i just get

```
Error: Can't find or load main class se/consys/silverkissen/heroku/Main
```

My war file lies in path `..\Silverkissen-API\target\silverkissen.war`

My heroku main class lies in path `..\Silverkissen-API\target\classes\se\consys\silverkissen\heroku\Main.class`

Thankful for any help.

Comment: Try `java -cp silverkissen.war se.consys.silverkissen.heroku.Main`

Comment: i get the same error, cant find or load main class se.consys.silverkissen.heroku.Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is most likely because the class files isn't incorporated into the `silverkissen.war` file. Meaning there is no `Main` function in the `war` file itself. Or that the entry function is some where else.

Or that it's packaged in some mysterious way that is beyond my understanding that's specific to maven, heroku etc.

But assuming you're standing in the project root structure, one level before the `target` folder usually where you'd normally have `src`, `target`, `pom.xml` and `system.properties`. I'd try running the following:

```
java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* se.consys.silverkissen.heroku.Main
```

And if you're on Windows that'd be:

```
java -cp target\classes;target\dependency\* se.consys.silverkissen.heroku.Main
```

That aught to do it. This will execute your project with class-path's in the runtime. Assuming my limited knowledge of Java is correct.

Someone with more experience can probably explain in detail why this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt in the location where your jar/war located
 And then run below command

java -jar silverkissen.war

Comment: When i do that it says theres no mainmanifest in silverkissen.war, so either i have to add the classpath in the manifest, or add it when i run the war file in the command line. Which i think is just easier, but i dont know how to specify it